# VS Code - Using Code Runner Extension to Run Programs on Virtual Machine (VM)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vagrant, virtual-machine, vagrant-windows

I develop on Windows using a Linux VM via Vagrant and Virtual Box. I'm trying to figure out how to get the Code Runner extension to run my files on the VM. The biggest hurdle so far is, for a given file, I need to convert from the Windows host path to the Linux guest path.

---

Background:

The [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension allows one to map file types to shell commands to run those files. For example,

`"java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt"`

tells Code Runner that when I try to run a Java file, it should `cd` to the directory that contains the file, and compile the file, and then run the compiled file. The mapping from file types to commands is called the `code-runner.executorMap` which is contained in `settings.json`. By adding the option

`"code-runner.runInTerminal": true`

to my `settings.json`, I can tell Code Runner to run in the integrated terminal. So by simply SSHing into my VM from the integrated terminal via `vagrant ssh`, I have code runner targeting the virtual machine.

This is where the problem comes in - Code Runner is using my Windows style paths and my Windows file structures as command line arguments to my VM.

For example, suppose my Windows file structure looks like `c:\a\b\c\d` and my VM has its root in `c` so that `c` and `d` are shared folders. If I want to run a file in `d`, the command `cd $dir` will tell my VM to do `cd c:\a\b\c\d`.

I have thought of workarounds like adding the following to my settings to run python files

`"python": "cd \"$(dirname \"$(locate -l1 $fileName)\")\"; python3 $fileName",`

This command, which runs on the integrated terminal (the VM) locates and changes to the directory which contains the file which is to be run. It then tells the python3 interpreter to run that file. However, this doesn't always work (e.g. multiple files with the same name), and requires me to update the database that `locate` depends upon every time I add a file.

There has to be some way to translate my Windows file paths to the paths on the virtual machine (so e.g. `c:\a\b\c\d` -> `/c/d`). Perhaps through Vagrant? I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed a workaround. I would still be interested in a "cleaner" solution.

---

The workaround is as follows:

Firstly, I wrote a Python script to convert from Windows Paths to paths on my virtual machine. The script takes in the windows path to a file and the file name as arguments.

```
#pathconverter.py
import sys
windows_path=sys.argv[1]
file_name=sys.argv[2]

path_to_vagrantfile = r"C:\Users\Evan\Google Drive\Development\Vagrantfile"
slashes=path_to_vagrantfile.count("\\")

y=windows_path.split("\\")[slashes:]
linux_path="/vagrant/"+'/'.join(y) + "/" + file_name
print(linux_path)
```

Thus the following code converts from a windows file location to one on my virtual machine (assuming you saved pathconverter.py at the root of your shared directory, `\vagrant` :

```
python3 \"/vagrant/pathconverter.py\" $dirWithoutTrailingSlash $fileName
```

Therefore, to run most files of various interpreted languages, I just supply the output of this command as an argument to the interpreter. For example, to run a Python script on my VM automatically, I just add the following line to the code-runner.executorMap:

```
"python": "python3 \"$(python3 \"/vagrant/pathconverter.py\" $dirWithoutTrailingSlash $fileName)\""
```

Or for Racket/scheme, I just do:

```
"scheme": "racket \"$(python3 \"/vagrant/pathconverter.py\" $dirWithoutTrailingSlash $fileName)\""
```